# Getting NameError: free variable 'Gamelogic' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python, function

I am trying to make a game in python. I, however, am getting this error: NameError: free variable 'Gamelogic' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope. The relevant code:

```
def Game():

    def logic():
        Gamelogic()

    selected_Card = input()
    logic()

    def Gamelogic():
        if selected_Card == "1":
            print("test")


Uno()
```

And it just gives NameError: free variable 'Gamelogic' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope. And I have to make the `GameLogic()` function after the rest of the code so that it can get use the variable in the function. Also when I just tried to make the `logic()` function with `Gamelogic()` in it where it just had the print statement and no if statement it printed correctly with no issues. (Full code here if you need it: https://pastebin.com/szPBW79e)

Comment: Can you post the complete error trace?

Comment: Inside `Game()`, you are defining `logic()`, and then almost immediately calling it.  At that point in time, the rest of `Game` (specifically, the definition of `Gamelogic()`) has not yet been executed.  You need to move the call to `logic()` down below the `def Gamelogic()`.

Comment: `Uno` is undefined.